# Switch Statement Help me Please

Tags: java, switch-statement, statements

I'm kinda new to this but? can anyone correct my first switch statement? I dont know what expression to use to start the case a:

and im not even sure if the starting declarations are even correct

```
    import java.io.*;
    public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input= br.readLine();

    System.out.println("Press Enter");
    System.out.println("a.Hello: Asks the name of the user.");
    System.out.println("b.Array: Input elements and search for a specified key and prints a     message.");
    System.out.println("c.MagicSquare: Displays [7][7] magic square.");
    System.out.println("d.Bubble Sort: Alphabetically sorts 20 employees using bubble sort.");
    System.out.println("e.Selection Sort: Alphabetically sorts 20 employees using selection sort");
    System.out.println("f.Insertion Sort: Alphabetically sorts 20 employees using Insertion sort");
    System.out.println("g.Factorial: Run the Factorial application");
    System.out.println("h.Triangle: Run the Triangle application."); 
    System.out.println("i.MergeSort: Performs the mergesort of a two class databasse.");
    System.out.println("j.Stack_1: Perform reversal of string.");
    System.out.println("k.Stack_2: Perform Infix Notation");
    System.out.println("l.Postfix: Perform Postfix Notation");
    System.out.println("m.Linked List");
   System.out.println("n.Queue:");
   System.out.println("o.Exit:");

        switch (input) {
            case a:

            String usersName;     
           String upperCaseName;  

           TextIO.put("Please enter your name: ");
           usersName = TextIO.getln();

           upperCaseName = usersName.toUpperCase();

           TextIO.putln("Hello, " + upperCaseName + ", nice to meet you!");


                     break;
            case b: 
        // Code for b execution here. Run array.
                     break;
            case c:  
        // Code for c execution here. magicsquare.
                     break;
            case d: 
        // Code for d execution here. Bubble sort.
                     break;
            case e:  
        // Code for e execution here. selection sort.
                     break;
            case f: 
        // Code for f execution here. insertion sort.
                     break;
            case g:  
        // Code for g execution here. recursion.
                     break;
            case h:  
        // Code for h execution here. mergesort.
                     break;
            case i:  
        // Code for b execution here. stack1.
                     break;
            case j: 
        // Code for b execution here. stack2.
                     break;
            case k: 
        // Code for b execution here. link list.
                     break;
            default: 
        System.out.println("Please input selection from a-o");
                     break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what you are trying to do. What is `a`? What is `b`?

Comment: Which version of the java you are using ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the letters are for the choices: you select a letter then the other programs will run sir.

Comment: What is the output and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: Instead of switching alphabets, try using numbers.

Comment: well im kinda having trouble sir, if the code for the hello world is right, or how should i start the expression with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, using

```
switch(input) {
    case "a":
        // do stuff
        break;
    case "b":
        // do more stuff
        break;
}
```

will work. 
Just another thing, if you are working in java 7 (java -version), you should be able to get rid of

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and replace it with

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = in.nextLine();
```

Which at least to me is a lot easier to use. Just import

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: im kinda working with that sir, thank you, and btw sir, the case "a" is already declared on my command Strings[], so i might not use it since im still adjusting sir, im verry sorry for being a newbie :(

Comment: I see that, this is just for general use. You can put anything in where it says do stuff. In your case, you would put in what you have.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points here

case statements are like this (pre 1.7)

```
char input = 'a';

switch (input) {
case 'a':
    break;
default :
    System.out.println("default");

}
```

for Java 1.7 and onwards you can also switch on Strings

```
String input = "a";

switch (input) {
case "a":
    printHelloUser();
    break;
default :
    System.out.println("default");

}

void printHelloUser () {
       String usersName;     
       String upperCaseName;  

       TextIO.put("Please enter your name: ");
       usersName = TextIO.getln();

       upperCaseName = usersName.toUpperCase();

       TextIO.putln("Hello, " + upperCaseName + ", nice to meet you!");


}
```

you may also want to consider `prompting` the user first before reading her input.

Comment: Provide an example of using strings and your answer is complete enough for an upvote ;)

Comment: where would the commands go sir? like the hello world? any example kind sir on the format? thanks a lot

Comment: @Aarowaim It is already there as of 7 minutes ago.  That bit down the bottom is using Strings.

Comment: The commands could be inline like you have them or you could create methods to do them - see my last example.

Comment: @Aarowaim, thats my problem sir, i only know very little on that. :(

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking the cases as Strings (you declare input as a String). You are calling variables called `a`, `b`, etc. Try putting them into quotation marks, as in `case: "a"`.